# Dubious user on MBP 10.12.5

Tags: macos, mac, root, users

I execute "dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'" and lists root permission users, like:

daemon,
Guest,
**hiddenuser**,
nobody,
"me",
root.

I don't know who is **hiddenuser** and how to remove it. could somebody help me, please?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998 Is this a company-owned laptop?

Comment: No, just my personal laptop.

Comment: Some report that certain software products add a hidden user. But, this account should still be visible and able to be deleted from User Accounts if you are running as root or admin.

Comment: That's right, but not my case. fortunately I found the solution. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7108801?start=0&tstart=0
thanks anyway.

Comment: Good. Go ahead and post the solution here as an answer and mark it as such. That way others will find your answer along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution to my problem.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7108801?start=0&tstart=0

> Back up all data.
>
> Launch the Directory Utility application. Depending on what version of
>   OS X you have, you may be able to do that by entering the first few
>   letters of its name in a Spotlight search. If that doesn't work,
>   triple-click anywhere in the line of text below on this page to select
>   it:
>
> /System/Library/CoreServices
>
> Right-click or control-click the selected text and select
>
> ```
>       Services ▹ Open
> ```
>
> from the contextual menu.* A folder named "CoreServices" will open.
>   The Directory Utility application is in that folder, or in a subfolder
>   named "Applications".
>
> In the Directory Utility window, click the lock icon and authenticate.
>   Select the Directory Editor tool in the toolbar. Select Users from the
>   Viewing menu in the toolbar, if not already selected. Locate the user
>   you want to delete in the list and click the minus-sign icon at the
>   bottom. Select Groups from the Viewing menu, and look for a group in
>   the list with the same name as the user you just deleted. If found,
>   delete. Quit Directory Utility.
>
> Be very careful when editing the directory. Many hidden users and
>   groups are present by default, and are needed for the normal operation
>   of OS X. Never delete or modify a directory entry unless you’re sure
>   you know what you’re doing. If in doubt, leave it alone.
>
> *If you don't see the contextual menu item, copy the selected text to the Clipboard by pressing the key combination  command-C. In the
>   Finder, select
>
> ```
>        Go ▹ Go to Folder...
> ```
>
> from the menu bar and paste into the box that opens (command-V). You
>   won't see what you pasted because a line break is included. Press
>   return.

Comment: Right now this is what we call a "link-only answer", which is an answer that will be deleted, because if the link ever changes, the answer is no longer helpful or valid. I've taken the liberty of editing the answer to include the entire body of the solution. Feel free to edit further if your solution differed in any specifics.

Comment: You're right! Looks better!

Comment: It isn't just about looking better, it is about making sure that here, in this answer, is everything necessary to solve the problem. Looks are nice because well-formated questions and answers are easier to read and understand than poorly formatted one's. But it's more important to have the entire solution here. If the answer comes from somewhere else, we link for proper attribution.